# Is there a way to import a texture in a specific format?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to load a rendered image from Blender into Unity. But I saved the image with a color depth of 16 bits per channel, and now I want to have the same accuracy inside Unity. However, when I put the texture on a material and zoom in a bit, it looks like this:

[image: 8 Bits]

As far as I can tell, this is only 8 bits per channel. What fixed it for me was overriding the format in the Texture Import Settings (from the default `RGBA Compressed DXT5` to `RGBA64`, because my image also has an alpha channel):

[image: Settings]

And now the image looks nice again:

[image: 16 Bits]

However, I would like to be able to import the image at runtime. So far I've been doing it like this:

```
Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(0, 0);
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
tex.LoadImage(bytes);
```

The problem is that, according to the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/530/Documentation/ScriptReference/Texture2D.LoadImage.html) for Texture2D.LoadImage, "PNG files are loaded into ARGB32 format" by default. And even if I set the format when creating the Texture2D, it seems to get overitten when I call LoadImage ("After LoadImage, texture size and format might change").

Is there a way to import an image in a specific format (at runtime)? Thanks in advance

Comment: Which Unity version are you using?

Comment: `LoadImage` is not there anymore in newer versions and you would rather use [`UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture.html)

Comment: I'm on 2020.3.5f1(LTS). Thanks for the advice, I've changed my code now to use Web requests instead. It works, but the problem is unfortunately still the same. The inspector says the imported image is in `ARGB8 UNORM` format

Comment: Oh I was wrong btw .. [`LoadImage`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ImageConversion.LoadImage.html) is still a thing .. I think it was just moved if I remember correctly

Comment: Alright, thanks for the correction. I'll move back to using `LoadImage` then. As long as I'm loading local files it seems a bit easier to use.

Comment: It's just a matter of desired behavior ... `LoadImage` uses the already loaded bytes and of course will freeze your app for the reading of the file and loading into the texture. The web request does both async so meanwhile your app keeps running without a freeze

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Subclass AssetPostprocessor:**

```
public class MyPostProcessor : AssetPostprocessor {
  public void OnPreprocessTexture() {
    if (assetPath.Contains("SomeFileName")) {
      TextureImporter textureImporter = (TextureImporter)assetImporter;
      TextureImporterPlatformSettings settings = new TextureImporterPlatformSettings();
      settings.textureCompression = TextureImporterCompression.Uncompressed;
      settings.format = TextureImporterFormat.RGBA64;
      textureImporter.SetPlatformTextureSettings(settings);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow. First of all, thanks for taking the time to answer on such an old thread. But as far as I understand this, I would still need to import the textures into the project beforehand (although I guess it would make that process easier). Anyways, I ended up getting it to work using a custom c++ dll that uses the opencv library and then passes a pointer to the data section of the created mat. But it's less than ideal and requires unsave c# code, the use of native & compute buffers as well as a custom shader to read the values from the buffer. That's why I decided against posting it here

Comment: This method allows you to do everything at runtime, in my usecase creating and saving an image to disk during gameplay and then loading it as a texture. Using this solution, I'm able to load the texture into the format desired, which wasn't working before the postprocessor (and which a quick google lead me to this unanswered thread, hence adding an answer for future users!).

Comment: That's awesome. I always thought that you could only import things in the editor (I'm sorry, propably should've checked that before adding my comment). Thanks for proving me wrong though :)